# vuejs how to compile single file component to js object

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have a simple Vue js single file component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    Hello!
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app'
  }
</script>
```

And I want to compile it to

```
{
  template: '<div>Hello!</div>'
}
```

of course, it should work with more complex examples, with included components and such.

How do I do that?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just load the file and substring the text out?, `const text = fs.readFileSync('component.vue'); return {templateText: text.substring(text.indexOf('<template>') + '<template>'.length, text.indexOf('</template>'))}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`vue-template-compiler` package](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/packages/vue-template-compiler):

Install it:

```
npm i vue-template-compiler
```

Use it (`test.vue` is a component from your example):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const compiler = require('vue-template-compiler');

const content = fs.readFileSync('./test.vue', 'utf-8');

const res = compiler.parseComponent(content);
const template = res.template.content.trim();

const result = { template };
console.log(result);
```

Result:

```
{ template: '<div>\n  Hello!\n</div>' }
```

Don't forget to add error checks to your code.

Comment: In that case, I can only get a template, but I want to compile it for future async import in the main project. Please Note that I want to import other components and libs to bundle them together.

Comment: So, you want to do something what [`vue-loader`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) is doing? Why?